# What property do I use to insert the Document ID in template

Tags: site-template, document-id

I've enabled the Document ID on my site collection. What property do I use to put a link in the page layout with the document ID. (to save the user from having to go to page > edit properties > view properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a snippet, and put that in the page template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following URL's

```
http://site/Library/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=XYZ
http://site/Library/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=XYZ
```

Change XYZ with ID of document.

Comment: how can I get that document ID programmatically?

Comment: You mean the ID of the current page?

Comment: yes - I want to insert that link, but include the document ID

Comment: You can get using `_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId`

Comment: could you give me a copy of a link I should use?

Comment: @TrevorNewhook sorry i didn't get what you asked. You can use JavaScript for dynamically populating the links.